# Python List, how to split it up in django template

Tags: python, django, list, django-templates, django-views

I have a python list that looks like this example:

```
[[' 1', ' 200', ' 30', ' item a'], [' 1', ' 500', ' 20', ' item b']]
```

This is then passed through to the template in django.

I am trying to generate a table using this data:

Each internal bracket (there are 2 in this example: `[' 1', ' 200', ' 30', ' item a']` and `[' 1', ' 500', ' 20', ' item b']` ) need to be in a new line in the table. So for this example, there would be 2 rows.

Each field within the internal brackets has to go in a new column in the table.. So this table will have 4 columns and 2 rows.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the basic Django documentation on templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic template tag you need is the [`for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) tag:

```
{% if my_list %}
    <table>
    {% for row in my_list %}
        <tr>
        {% for item in row %}
            <td>{{ item }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endif %}
```

I also use an `if` tag so you don't end up with an empty set of `table` tags if there are no rows in the list.

Answer (score 2):

[`{% for ... %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)